# Mule ESB Email Attachment filter

Tags: email, mule, filtering

Just wanted to ask some help on the Inbound Email scenario. I have setup one mailbox to receive CSV files that contains different mappings for each. I know I can use the choice filetr for it but I can seem to get the correct attachment name values on the email. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a general answer for situations like this.

When you don't know exactly what property values you are looking for, or what classtype they are, use the debugger in Anypoint Studio. Open your project, add a logger and set a breakpoint on it just after your inbound, and run it in debug mode. Trigger the flow to start, in this case by sending an email to the box it is polling.

Next, you will see the debug perspective and will be able to see the attachment as an inbound property (if i remember correctly). You will also see its type. If you are handling a more complex object, just add a Groovy Script to build the logic needed, and set a simple flag in another property that you will later use in your filter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Emil, thanks for your answer. that's what I'm currently doing in the debugger. the inbound properties are acting up on the attachment names. I was actually curious if you can just pick up the mails with the correct attachment on it and leave the others for the other flows to pick it up.Now Im  having some workarounds with the subject name but I still prefer if I can pick it up by attachment name.